# How can I change to font used by hepparticles/hepnames with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, libertine

I am trying to get the hepparticles/hepnames packages to work with XeLaTeX. I 
am using Libertine as serif font and Biolinum as sans font. The particle names are somehow rendered in the wrong font.

The HEP packages insert glyphs for particle names used in high-energy physics. They should (I think) use the current font and style, but which font they actually use is inconsistent. In the MWEs below, I used a simple particle name (B) for comparison of a normal rendering of the letter B and the particle name inserted with the \PB macro, which should be identical.

I tried different orders for the loading of the packages:

## fontspec loaded *before* HEP packages

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum}

\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        ~  & Normal & textsf       & textit       & textsf+textit         \\
        B  & B      & \textsf{B}   & \textit{B}   & \textit{\textsf{B}}   \\
        PB & \PB    & \textsf{\PB} & \textit{\PB} & \textit{\textsf{\PB}} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The normal glyph uses the wrong font, the sf glyph uses the wrong font *and* serifs, but the italic versions are both correct:

[image]

## fontspec loaded *after* HEP packages

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        ~  & Normal & textsf       & textit       & textsf+textit         \\
        B  & B      & \textsf{B}   & \textit{B}   & \textit{\textsf{B}}   \\
        PB & \PB    & \textsf{\PB} & \textit{\PB} & \textit{\textsf{\PB}} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

All glyphs use the correct style, but all have the wrong font *except* the serif-italic glyph.

[image]

Next I used the libertine/biolinum packages instead of fontspec, and compiled the file with pdflatex as well for comparison:

## font packages loaded *after* HEP packages

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}

\usepackage{libertineRoman}
\usepackage{biolinum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        ~  & Normal & textsf       & textif       & textsf+textit         \\
        B  & B      & \textsf{B}   & \textit{B}   & \textit{\textsf{B}}   \\
        PB & \PB    & \textsf{\PB} & \textit{\PB} & \textit{\textsf{\PB}} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### pdflatex

All glyphs have correct style and wrong font:

[image]

### xelatex

All glyphs use the correct style, but all have the wrong font *except* the serif-italic glyph.

[image]

## font packages loaded *before* HEP packages

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{libertineRoman}
\usepackage{biolinum}

\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        ~  & Normal & textsf       & textit       & textsf+textit         \\
        B  & B      & \textsf{B}   & \textit{B}   & \textit{\textsf{B}}   \\
        PB & \PB    & \textsf{\PB} & \textit{\PB} & \textit{\textsf{\PB}} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### pdflatex

All glyphs use the correct style, and all have the correct font *except* the serif-italic glyph. (This would be fine for me, except that I want to use xelatex.)

[image]

### xelatex

The normal glyph uses the wrong font, the sf glyph uses the wrong font *and* serifs, but the italic versions are both correct:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The macros such as `\PB` use math mode for their job. This is surely going to give problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so egreg's comment pointed me in the right direction. I tried using `mathspec` to change the math fonts, with not luck. After taking a closer look at the macros in `hepparticles`, I fount that they use `\mathup` and similar macros for rendering the particle names. I couldn't find out how to change those with `mathspec`, so I switched to `unicode-math` and found a working configuration that gives a satisfactory result:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont[BoldItalicFont=Linux Biolinum O Bold Oblique]{Linux Biolinum}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Linux Libertine}

\setmathfont[range=\mathrm]{Linux Libertine}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Linux Libertine Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Linux Libertine Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine Bold Italic}

\setmathfont[range=\mathsf]{Linux Biolinum}
\setmathfont[range=\mathsfup]{Linux Biolinum}
\setmathfont[range=\mathsfit]{Linux Biolinum Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfsf]{Linux Biolinum Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfsfit]{Linux Biolinum O Bold Oblique}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        ~  & Normal & textsf       & textit       & textsf+textit         \\
        B  & B      & \textsf{B}   & \textit{B}   & \textit{\textsf{B}}   \\
        PB & \PB    & \textsf{\PB} & \textit{\PB} & \textit{\textsf{\PB}} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I ran into a follow-up problem, which is discussed in [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241382/how-can-i-set-the-boldmath-font-with-unicode-math).