# How can I set the \boldmath font with unicode-math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I am trying to typeset a document in Linux Libertine, and I want to use the font for alphanumeric characters in math mode as well. I am using `unicode-math`, not `mathspec`, because I need to specify alphabets like `mathup` explicitly for compatibility with packages like `hepnames`. I did not find a way to do that with `mathspec`. The engine I use is XeLaTeX. I initially specify TeX Gyre Pagella Math as a complete math font for symbols etc. I want the subsequent declarations to overwrite the font for text characters as Libertine.

I find several problems, illustrated by the MWE below:

1. The `\boldmath` switch doesn't do anything.
2. Numbers are not rendered correctly in bold and italic, only letters.
3. `\mathbf` (the last "A = 1" in the MWE) is rendered in Pagella, not in Libertine at all.

I already tried adding `/{latin,Latin,num}` to the `range` declarations, without success. What am I missing here?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[%
    Ligatures=TeX,
    BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
    ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
    BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf]
    {LinLibertine_R.otf}

\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{LinLibertine_RB.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{LinLibertine_RI.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{LinLibertine_RBI.otf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        Text     & A = 1               & \textit{B = 2}\\
        Textbf   & \textbf{A = 1}      & \textbf{\textit{B = 2}}\\
        Math     & $A = 1$             & $\mathit{B = 2}$\\
        Boldmath & {\boldmath $A = 1$} & {\boldmath $\mathit{B = 2}$}\\
        Mathbf   & $\mathbf{A = 1}$    & $\mathbfit{B = 2}$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without font changes, everything looks OK:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        Text     & A = 1               & \textit{B = 2}\\
        Textbf   & \textbf{A = 1}      & \textbf{\textit{B = 2}}\\
        Math     & $A = 1$             & $\mathit{B = 2}$\\
        Boldmath & {\boldmath $A = 1$} & {\boldmath $\mathit{B = 2}$}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: by default unicode-math sets up `\boldmath` _not_ to switch fonts but rather to switch characters into the bold math alphabet range starting at U+1d400 in the current math font, so the appearance depends on the glyphs in that range.

Comment: `\boldmath` is shorthand for `\mathversion{bold}` unicode-math allows a `version=bold` key in its font setting option to specify fonts to use in that case.

Comment: I already  looked ad `version=bold`. If I add lines like `\setmathfont[range=\mathup,version=bold]{LinLibertine_RB.otf}` or `\setmathfont[range=\mathit,version=bold]{LinLibertine_RBI.otf}`, _all_ characters in math mode become bold/italic. I guess I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I started playing around with `version=bold`, as David suggested, but that kept turning *all* my math mode text bold. In the end I switched from file names to system font names. (I wanted to avoid that initially, since I am working on the same document from several different machines.) With system font names, `\boldmath`  worked immediately and automatically. I also found that `\mathbfup` must be specified instead of `\mathbf`.

Another problem with using system font names is that, for some reason, the semi-bold Libertine style is loaded per default as bold. That is the reason for the `BoldFont` specification in the MWE below.

The solution is not perfect. You can see that all numbers in math mode are rendered upright, even in `\mathit`. Also, the number in `\mathbfit` is not bold. All fonts are correct though, and it's good enough for my purposes.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[
    BoldFont=Linux Libertine Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=Linux Libertine Bold Italic]
    {Linux Libertine}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup,
    BoldFont=Linux Libertine Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=Linux Libertine Bold Italic]
    {Linux Libertine}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit,
    BoldFont=Linux Libertine Bold Italic]
    {Linux Libertine Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine Bold Italic}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        ~        &\ Regular             &\ Italic\\
        Text     &\ A = 1               &\ \textit{A = 1}\\
        Textbf   &\ \textbf{A = 1}      &\ \textbf{\textit{A = 1}}\\
        Math     &\ $A = 1$             &\ $\mathit{A = 1}$\\
        Boldmath &\ {\boldmath $A = 1$} &\ {\boldmath $\mathit{A = 1}$}\\
        Mathbf   &\ $\mathbf{A = 1}$    &\ $\mathbfit{A = 1}$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[tg85 noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241423/156280) two issues with the answer that he provided to his own question:

> The solution is not perfect. You can see that all numbers in math mode are rendered upright, even in `\mathit`. Also, the number in `\mathbfit` is not bold. All fonts are correct though, and it's good enough for my purposes.

The [*unicode-math* manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) (Figure 7) states that the upright shape is actually chosen on purpose for numerals because they “should always be taken from the upright font even in the italic style.” In line with this statement, it seems that Unicode does not define slots for italic digits—while it does define slots for bold digits, sans-serif digits, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode#Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols_block.

I can understand, however, that one still wishes the typesetting produced by *unicode-math* to be consistent with the original LaTeX-based typesetting, where `\mathit{1}` produces an italic digit one. Therefore, inspired by [tg85’s code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241423/156280), I came up with a solution that fixes these two issues (also works with LuaLaTeX):

```latex
% !TEX program = xelatex


\documentclass{minimal}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[
   mathit = sym, mathup = sym, mathbf = sym,
   math-style = ISO, bold-style = ISO
]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}[
   ItalicFont = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
   BoldFont = LinLibertine_RB.otf,
   BoldItalicFont = LinLibertine_RBI.otf
]
\setmonofont{FiraMono-Medium.otf}[
   Scale = 0.81,
   Color = DarkBlue
]

\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}[
   BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold.otf
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}[
   version = mathitVersion
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}[
   version = mathbfitVersion
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[
   version = boldmathVersion
]

\setmathfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}[
   range = up/{num, latin, Latin, greek, Greek},
   BoldFont = LinLibertine_RB.otf
]
\setmathfont{LinLibertine_RI.otf}[
   range = it/{num, latin, Latin, greek, Greek},
   BoldFont = LinLibertine_RBI.otf,
   NFSSFamily = mathitalic
]
\setmathfont{LinLibertine_RBI.otf}[
   range = bfit/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek},
   NFSSFamily = mathbolditalic
]
\setmathfont{LinLibertine_RB.otf}[
   range = bfup/{num, latin, Latin, greek, Greek}
]

\newif \ifBoldMath \BoldMathfalse
\let \mathversionorig \mathversion
\renewcommand{\mathversion}[1]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{bold}}{%
      \BoldMathtrue%
   }{%
      \BoldMathfalse%
   }%
   \mathversionorig{#1}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
   \let \mathitorig \mathit%
   \renewcommand{\mathit}[1]{%
      \ifBoldMath%
         \textbf{%
            \SetSymbolFont{__um_fam1}{boldmathVersion}{TU}{mathbolditalic}{b}{it}%
            \SetSymbolFont{__um_fam2}{boldmathVersion}{TU}{mathbolditalic}{b}{it}%
            \mathversion{boldmathVersion}%
            \(\mathitorig{#1}\)%
         }
      \else%
         \textit{%
            \SetSymbolFont{__um_fam1}{mathitVersion}{TU}{mathitalic}{m}{it}%
            \mathversion{mathitVersion}%
            \(\mathitorig{#1}\)%
         }%
      \fi%
   }%
   \let \mathbfitorig \mathbfit%
   \renewcommand{\mathbfit}[1]{{%
      \textbf{%
          \SetSymbolFont{__um_fam1}{mathbfitVersion}{TU}{mathbolditalic}{b}{it}%
          \mathversion{mathbfitVersion}%
          \(\mathbfitorig{#1}\)%
      }%
   }}%
}

\newcommand{\testUnicodeMath}{%
   \bigskip
   \begin{tabular}{l @{\quad}l @{\quad} l @{\quad} l @{\quad} l}
       Row
       & Math version/alphabet
       & Regular
       & Upright
       & Italic \\[\medskipamount]
       1
       & Text
       & A = 1a
       & \textup{B = 2b}
       & \textit{C = 3c} \\
       2 &
       \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}
       & \textbf{A = 1a}
       & \textbf{\textup{B = 2b}}
       & \textbf{\textit{C = 3c}} \\
       3
       & \texttt{\textbackslash mathversion\{normal\}} (default)
       & $A = 1a + \beta \times \Gamma \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathup{d}x}{2}$
       & $\mathup{B = 2b + \beta \times \Gamma}$
       & $\mathit{C = 3c + \beta \times \Gamma}$ \\
       4
       & \texttt{\textbackslash mathversion\{bold\}}/\texttt{\textbackslash boldmath}
       & \boldmath $A = 1a + \beta \times \Gamma \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathup{d}x}{2}$
       & \boldmath $\mathup{B = 2b + \beta \times \Gamma}$
       & \boldmath $\mathit{C = 3c + \beta \times \Gamma}$ \\
       5
       & \texttt{\textbackslash mathbf}/\texttt{\textbackslash mathbfup}/\texttt{\textbackslash mathbfit}
       & $\mathbf{A = 1a + \beta \times \Gamma \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathup{d}x}{2}}$
       & $\mathbfup{B = 2b + \beta \times \Gamma}$
       & $\mathbfit{C = 3c + \beta \times \Gamma}$ \\
   \end{tabular}%
   \bigskip
   \bigskip
}


\begin{document}

\testUnicodeMath

\textit{Check that everything works properly by invoking it a~second time:}

\testUnicodeMath

\textit{Check that everything works properly by invoking it a~third time:}

\testUnicodeMath

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output—note that the “3” in table row 3 is now italic, and it is bold italic in table rows 4 and 5:

[image: \mathit and \mathbfit fixed]

Also note the contrast between `\mathversion{bold}`/`\boldmath` and `\mathbf`/`\mathbfup`/`\mathbfit`: the former also makes all operators, integrals, etc. bold, while the latter only affects letters and digits.

Comment: I edited my solution because the previous version generated a “Too many symbol fonts declared” error when using `\mathit` repeatedly.

Answer (score -2):

Using the package amsbsy and \pmb seems to get the boldmath.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\setmainfont[%
Ligatures=TeX,
BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf]
{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{LinLibertine_RB.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{LinLibertine_RI.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{LinLibertine_RBI.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Text     & A = 1               & \textit{B = 2}\\
    Textbf   & \textbf{A = 1}      & \textbf{\textit{B = 2}}\\
    Math     & $A = 1$             & $\mathit{B = 2}$\\
    Boldmath & { $\pmb{A = 1}$} & {$\pmb{\mathit{B = 2}}$}\\
    Mathbf   & $\mathbf{A = 1}$    & $\mathbfit{B = 2}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to produce a different (third?) font. https://imgur.com/Bw48aZc

Comment: I do not see any different font!

Comment: `\pmb` just prints three copies of the glyph slightly offset, it is not a true bold font.

Comment: don't use `\pmb` unless you are desperate (and then consider not using it:-)

Answer (score -3):

With `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{hepnames}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\tabcolsep=10pt
    \begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily\textbackslash}lll}
    normalfont & Regular           &\itshape Italic\\
    textnormal & A = 1             & \textit{A = 1}\\
    textbf     & \textbf{A = 1}    & \textbf{\textit{A = 1}}\\
    mathup     & $\mathup{A} = 1$  & $A = 1$\\
    symbf      & $\symbfup{A = 1}$ & $\symbfit{A = 1}$\\
    mathbf     & $\mathbf{A = 1}$  & $\mathbfit{A = 1}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]