# non-italic symbols of the hepnames package not printing with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, macros

for typsetting particles from physics the hepnames package is often used. After an upgrade to a win10 PC, I found that the symbols are not printing anymore - no error messages.

I use pdfLatex and found relating topics for

- luatex : [How do I get the XITS font to work with unicode-math and hepnames in lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296603/how-do-i-get-the-xits-font-to-work-with-unicode-math-and-hepnames-in-lualatex)
- xetex  : [How can I set the \boldmath font with unicode-math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241382/how-can-i-set-the-boldmath-font-with-unicode-math)

Here is my minimal example:

```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{hepnames}

  \begin{document}  

    \begin{itemize}
      \item $\Pneutron$ should give $\mathrm{n}$   %does not print
      \item $\Pfermion$ should give an $f$         %prints 
      \item $\APnue$ should give $\bar{\nu}$       %does not print
    \end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is likely related to the italic font style. Using

```
\usepackage[italic]{hepnames}
```

will print all of the above examples.

This is however hardly a good fix for the package and will typeset all particle symbols in italic. Unfortunately pdflatex does not throw an error or a warning during compilation.

Any suggestions?

Best, Marc

Comment: your example works in texlive 2018 but not 2019 or 2020, so it should be possible to trace the differences and see what changed. I'll look later if no one else has answered  (welcome to the site by the way and thanks for the nice minimal example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's the change of NFSS: the detection code in `hepnames` doesn't 'know' `up` as a shape

Comment: @JosephWright that was my guess but was confused by it working in 2019, or perhaps my tl2019 install is not exactly standard anymore:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle we changed that already in tl2019.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that would explain it...

Comment: The same problem on MikTeX/Win10 and TL2020/Fedora33. Fix below works. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `hepnames` package relies on `\updefault` being `n`, but this has changed to `up` and `n` is now `\shapedefault`.

Fix:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hepnames}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@HepConStyle
 {\edef\@upcode{\updefault}}
 {\ifdefined\shapedefault\edef\@upcode{\shapedefault}\else\edef\@upcode{\updefault}\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\Pneutron$ should give $\mathrm{n}$   %does not print

\item $\Pfermion$ should give an $f$         %prints

\item $\APnue$ should give $\bar{\nu}$       %does not print
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]