# Does anyone know how to use LaTeX to write this expression?

Tags: math-mode, titles, bold

[image]

I am new to LaTeX. Does anyone know how to write the above expression? I tried a lot but always with errors. This is what I have tried. Thanks in advance.

```
\title{\textbf{Search for the decay \emph{B$^+$}{$\rightarrow$}\emph{K$^+$} }}
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595

Comment: I don't get any errors when I use your code within a minimal document.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, considerin accepting one of the given answers.

Comment: Any reason why you don't accept one of the provided answers?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, but how to accept ? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: You can accept one of the answers. Then the answer gets an green check mark.

Answer (score 4):

This is a start. Make sure you [read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595) this and [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) plus a general introduction in LaTeX, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
Text $\boldsymbol{a^\pm + b ^\mp}$ Text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Unrelated, but maybe consider *not* to use math in headings and titles. Maybe you can describe it verbally as in "Decay of the Beta Particle" instead of "Decay of the `$\boldmath\beta$` Particle".

Comment: Welcome back... very happy to see you after some break....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks for remembering me :). I had some job-related stress the past 1.5 years.

Answer (score 2):

To get bold text and matching bold math, format your headers with `\boldmath` as well as `\bfseries`.  In PDFLaTeX, you will generally get better results with `\usepackage{bm}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Or your font package of choice.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\title{\boldmath\bfseries Search for the decay \( B^{+} \rightarrow K^{+}\tau^{+}\mu^{+} \)}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

You can also use the `\boldsymbol` command from `amsmath` (or `amsbsy`) to embolden an expression within math mode, as in Manuel Kuehner’s answer.

Both of these commands will also work on LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with `unicode-math`, **if** you load a bold math font.  Only a few OpenType math fonts come with them, such as XITS Math and KP Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{KpRoman}[
  UprightFont = *-Light ,
  ItalicFont = *-LightItalic ,
  BoldFont = *-Semibold ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf ]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Light}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Semibold}[version=bold]

\title{\boldmath\bfseries Search for the decay \( B^{+} \rightarrow K^{+}\tau^{+}\mu^{+} \)}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The decay \( B^{+} \rightarrow K^{+}\tau^{+}\mu^{+} \) ....
\end{document}
```

[image: KP Fonts sample]

However, you can always fake one with `FakeBold=`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold = 0.10 ]

\title{\boldmath\bfseries Search for the decay \( B^{+} \rightarrow K^{+}\tau^{+}\mu^{+} \)}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The decay \( B^{+} \rightarrow K^{+}\tau^{+}\mu^{+} \) ....
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

Comment: +1: Very sophisticated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hepnames` package, but it needs a patch as explained at [non-italic symbols of the hepnames package not printing with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541092/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hepnames}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@HepConStyle
 {\edef\@upcode{\updefault}}
 {\ifdefined\shapedefault\edef\@upcode{\shapedefault}\else\edef\@upcode{\updefault}\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Search for the decay $\PBplus\to\PKplus\Ptaump\Pmupm$}

Search for the decay $\PBplus\to\PKplus\Ptaump\Pmupm$

\end{document}
```

Note that boldface in section titles is automatically taken into account.

[image]

If you prefer italic for all particle names, you do

```
\usepackage[italic]{hepnames}
```

and the output would be

[image]

Comment: +1: Crazy how many domain-specific packages exist.