# No output by hepparticles

Tags: pdftex

im trying to use the `hepparticles` package.

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hepparticles}

\begin{document}
foo \HepParticle{H}{1}{2} $\HepParticle{H}{}{}\to \HepParticle{b}{}{}\HepParticle{b}{}{}$ \HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} bar
\end{document}
```

The pdf does not contain any particle symbols:
[image]

This is the output of `pdflatex`:

```
❯ pdflatex test.tex                       
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hepparticles/hepparticles.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subdepth/subdepth.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux
) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 17922 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Ideally I want to use `lualatex` later, but in this case the result is the same with both.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am able to reproduce this problem with TeX Live 2020 or later. No problems seem to occur with TeX Live 2019. However, you seem to use TeX Live 2019, which is curious.

Comment: Hi, what do you wonna to be printed out? Do you have picture of result what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has already been discussed and solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541092/non-italic-symbols-of-the-hepnames-package-not-printing-with-pdflatex). The problem lies in a change of a macro definition in newer TeX versions.

You can solve this problem by inserting a certain snippet of code (which has been taken from the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541095/47927) to the above liked discussion) as follows:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hepparticles}

%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@HepConStyle
 {\edef\@upcode{\updefault}}
 {\ifdefined\shapedefault\edef\@upcode{\shapedefault}\else\edef\@upcode{\updefault}\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%

\begin{document}
foo \HepParticle{H}{1}{2} $\HepParticle{H}{}{}\to \HepParticle{b}{}{}\HepParticle{b}{}{}$ \HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} bar
\end{document}
```

[image]